# How to parse several positional arguments mixed with options?

Tags: python, argparse

I need to parse command line string like this:

```
node frontend.js project1.pro project2.pro ... projectN.pro --spec linux-g++ CONFIG+=debug CONFIG+=qml_debug -opt1 value1 ... -opt2 value2
```

I.e. options (with hyphen) and positional arguments (without it at start)
can be mixed by user :(

I try to specify several positional arguments, but this was not work:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='PROG')
parser.add_argument('--foo')
parser.add_argument('project_files', default=[], nargs='+')
parser.add_argument('-spec',  nargs=1,  required=True)
parser.add_argument('other_options',  default=[],  nargs='+')
print(parser.parse_args('--foo B project_1.pro project_2.pro -spec linux-g++ CONFIG+=debug CONFIG+=qml_debug'.split()))
```

But got such error:

```
PROG: error: unrecognized arguments: CONFIG+=debug CONFIG+=qml_debug
```

What am doing wrong?
Thanks!

P.S. Sorry if the question is stupid, i am new in Python and argument parsing using such libraries. 
P.P.S. arguments "node frontend.js" are ignored

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
print(parser.parse_args('--foo B project_1.pro project_2.pro -spec linux-g++'.split()))
```

produces

```
Namespace(foo='B', other_options=['project_2.pro'], project_files=['project_1.pro'], spec=['linux-g++'])
```

'progject_2.pro' gets assigned to `other_options` rather than to `project_files`.  That's because of how the 2 `nargs='+'` are handled.

`parse_args` alternates handling positionals and optionals (flagged).  And it tries to handle as many positionals as will fit.  That can lead to unexpected results when one or more of them have these 'open-ended' `nargs` like `+` and `*`.

I'd suggest changing to:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='PROG')
parser.add_argument('--foo')
parser.add_argument('project_files', nargs='+')
parser.add_argument('--spec')
parser.add_argument('--other',  nargs='+')
print(parser.parse_args('--foo B project_1.pro project_2.pro --spec linux-g++'.split()))

print(parser.parse_args('--foo B project_1.pro project_2.pro --spec linux-g++ --other CONFIG+=debug CONFIG+=qml_debug'.split()))
```

resulting in

```
2343:~/mypy$ python stack46702635.py 
Namespace(foo='B', other=None, project_files=['project_1.pro', 'project_2.pro'], spec='linux-g++')
Namespace(foo='B', other=['CONFIG+=debug', 'CONFIG+=qml_debug'], project_files=['project_1.pro', 'project_2.pro'], spec='linux-g++')
```

https://bugs.python.org/issue15112 - `argparse: nargs='*' positional argument doesn't accept any items if preceded by an option and another positional`

https://bugs.python.org/issue9338 - `argparse optionals with nargs='?', '*' or '+' can't be followed by positionals`

---

You could omit the `other` argument, and use `parse_known_args`.  The unknown strings are returned in a separate list.

```
#parser.add_argument('other',  nargs='...')
print(parser.parse_known_args('--foo B project_1.pro project_2.pro --spec linux-g++'.split()))

print(parser.parse_known_args('--foo B project_1.pro project_2.pro --spec linux-g++ CONFIG+=debug CONFIG+=qml_debug'.split()))

0859:~/mypy$ python stack46702635.py 
(Namespace(foo='B', project_files=['project_1.pro', 'project_2.pro'], spec='linux-g++'), [])
(Namespace(foo='B', project_files=['project_1.pro', 'project_2.pro'], spec='linux-g++'), ['CONFIG+=debug', 'CONFIG+=qml_debug'])
```

Earlier parsers like `optparse` and `getopt` just handled the flagged arguments, and returned the rest as a list.  You had to parse those yourself.

Comment: So, can have two or more groups of positional arguments, separated by "usual" options - or argparse cannot do so?

Comment: UPD: a problem is what i should support command line format of the other application (Qt qmake), so i can't change option format :(

Comment: The fact that `-spec` was defined between two positionals doesn't matter.  Parsing is determined by the order in the commandline.  There are a couple of bug/issues about refining this kind of processing but no formal changes have been made.

Comment: So, if i can't append new option "--other", `argparse` will be unavailable to parse my command line?

Comment: I added a `parse_known_args` idea.

Comment: Yes, this way can be used as final solution. Thanks!